# Client side validation, Regext to match <script> tag,or how to  validate blog post to prevent script posting

Tags: regex, asp.net-mvc-3

I was looking for regex to match script tag, i am using ASP.NET MVC 3.0 unobtrusive validation.

I found this regexp `"^[<script (.|\n)?>(.|\n)*?</script>]*$"` but i cant make it work properly, it is mating not only script tags for some rason.

How to fix that?

here is some examples:

1)

```
<script>
alert("a");
</script>
<div style="clear:both"><br /></div>
```

2)

```
<script src="/anypath" type="text/javascript">antything
</script>
<div style="clear:both"><br /></div>
```

3)

```
<div style="clear:both"><br /></div>
<script>

</script>
```

What I ma trying to do - a want to validate blog post input to prevent post scripts as a part of blog post.

Comment: Your usage of `[` and `]` is VERY wrong. Read the docs again.

Comment: Concur with @leppie; you should elaborate on this and post it as an answer.

Comment: You could HTML encode the blog post when you display it, that would sanitize any script tags it contained. http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/04/06/new-lt-gt-syntax-for-html-encoding-output-in-asp-net-4-and-asp-net-mvc-2.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I think you would match script tags with a simpler regex:

```
(<script.*?>.*?</script>)
```